# How to resolve Marshal.dump "no marshal_dump is defined for class Proc" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

Suppose I have a `User < ActiveRecord::Base`.
Now, suppose I would like to create a user instance, validate it and store it in the session if I can not save it.

```
user = User.new
...
session[:new_user] = user unless user.save
...
```

Using the ActiveRecord session one might end up with `no marshal_dump is defined for class Proc` coming from `Marshal.dump`.

Now, what is the best way to resolve such serialization errors (locate the "invalid" `Proc` objects) for an object (does not have to be AR in general) ?

Answer (score 5):

Usually it's better to store the user *id* in the session, not the `User` instance itself. This does mean you have to do a db (or memcache) lookup for authenticated requests, but it saves you a ton of headaches around serialization/caching that you'd otherwise have to deal with.

Also, it's not an "invalid" `Proc` in some sense. `Proc` instances are containers for Ruby code and application state and therefore cannot be serialized, ever.

Comment: thx but as my AR sample suggest I can not store a user id - it's a transient instance. I know it's agains the "rails" way but hey it's supposed to be a session store for arbitrary objects ... lame that one can't store model instances :-( ... I do not found memcache a usable option as well.

Comment: You can store model instances, you just have to figure out what is causing it to be unserializable. Where are you storing a `Proc` instance? It might be a plugin, or it might be something you're doing explicitly. This isn't really a drawback of ActiveRecord or Ruby - virtually every programming environment that supports closures will have this restriction.

Comment: I agree, now the question was: "what is the best way to resolve such serialization errors (locate the Proc objects) ?" ...

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, I would say, store only the `attributes`. [`ActiveRecord::Base#attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes) returns a hash of the attributes stored in the database, so it will almost certainly not contain any `Proc`s.

```
session[:new_user] = user.attributes unless user.save
```

In general, however, a simple way is to use `inspect` on the object you're trying to marshal.

```
puts obj.inspect
```

or equivalently

```
p obj
```

Usually this will print internal objects, and you can see whether something is a Proc. If you still can't find it and you need to dig deeper, you can inspect all the member variables of the object.

```
obj.instance_variables.each do |var|
  puts "#{var} = #{obj.instance_eval(var).inspect}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when trying to store an unsaved AR object in the session.
Since I was dealing with an arbitrary model, I had to store both the class and attributes 
in the session so that I could rebuild it later.  I solved this by saving the class and attributes in the session together:

```
session[:key] = {:klass => obj.class.to_s, :attributes => obj.attributes}
```

I could then recreated the object from the session

```
obj = session[:key][:klass].constantize.new(session[:key][:attributes])
```