# TypeError (no _dump_data is defined for class Proc):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to store a value in the session using the below code in my rails application

```
session[:key] = value
```

And i get the below error

```
TypeError (no _dump_data is defined for class Proc):
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:53:in `dump'
 activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:53:in `generate'
 actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:300:in `[]='
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:67:in    `set_cookie'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:330:in `commit_session'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:206:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9)    lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668030/how-to-resolve-marshal-dump-no-marshal-dump-is-defined-for-class-proc-error

Answer (score 7):

Your `value` is either a Proc or has s Proc nested inside of it somewhere. Procs and lambdas cannot be serialized/marshaled/dumped because they are closures. Closures depend on what is in memory at the time they are created, and therefore cannot be unserialized correctly later.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970/how-do-i-marshal-a-lambda-proc-in-ruby%20this%20answer).

I'm not sure what I will be doing in my case, it looks like I will have to figure out a way to accomplish my task without relying on Procs.

Answer (score 2):

What is this value? Is it a complicated object? An active record instance maybe?

I had the same problem trying to put an FourSquare client object into the session.
I've changed to create a new instance every time, instead of recovering from session, and it worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `use Rack::Session::Pool` instead of plain `enable :sessions`? `Rack::Sessions::Pool` allows for local storage of unserialisable objects, while storing the ID to the object in the cookie so it can be retrieved.

I used it to retain a(n) (unserialisable) database connection across Sinatra routes.

From http://www.getlaura.com/how-to-enable-sessions-with-sinatra/

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'customer.rb'

class SinatraApp < Sinatra::Base

use Rack::Session::Pool

get '/welcome' do
  name = session[:customer].name
  "Hello, #{name}!"
end

post '/:name' do
  session[:customer] = Customer.new(params[:name])
  redirect '/welcome'
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we were caching an ActiveRecord model and that model had an @ variable that contained a lambda function. That was causing the issue.